# ansible show hostnames in play recap summary instead of IPs when using ec2 dynamic inventory?

Tags: ansible, amazon-ec2

how to make ansible show host names from [ec2 dynamic inventory tags](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/stable-2.9/contrib/inventory/ec2.py) or /etc/hosts instead of IPs in PLAY RECAP SUMMARY:

Output:

```
PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************************
174.129.7.83              : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
18.20.83.221              : ok=13   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Expected:

---

```
webserver1 or ec2 name tag              : ok=9    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
webserver2 or ec2 name tag             : ok=13   changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

So that I don't have to search for IPs and host names again

Edit 1:
Is there any config line for this in ansible.cfg?

Comment: My `ansible` shows inventory hostnames as default - you might want to show us what you have set in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg` and other config files

Comment: I am using ec2 dynamic inventory file @Panki

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution in `ec2.ini` file

```
# This allows you to override the inventory_name with an ec2 variable, instead
# of using the destination_variable above. Addressing (aka ansible_ssh_host)
# will still use destination_variable. Tags should be written as 'tag_TAGNAME'.
hostname_variable = tag_Name
```